# In Django, how do I order_by() when reaching across tables?

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm trying to filter my Friendships objects and then order_by user.first_name, but it's not working. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my models:

```
class Friendships(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name="usersfriend")
    friend = models.ForeignKey('Users', models.DO_NOTHING, related_name ="friendsfriend")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'friendships'

class Users(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
```

My query is as follows, which returns my needed Friendships, but the order is not correct. I've tried a number of different combinations and examples but just am not sure what I'm not correctly understanding:

My query in my controller:

```
ordered_friends = Friendships.objects.filter(user__id=1).order_by('user__first_name')
for ordered_friend in ordered_friends:
    print ordered_friend.friend.first_name, ordered_friend.friend.last_name
```

Note, I've tried a number of combinations in place of `user__first_name` and I know this is where I'm failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your order by that's wrong but what you do with the results. Let us digest the following, particularly line 3

```
ordered_friends = Friendships.objects.filter(user__id=1).order_by('user__first_name')
for ordered_friend in ordered_friends:
    print ordered_friend.friend.first_name, ordered_friend.friend.last_name
```

In `ordered_friend` you have an instance of `FriendShip` each ordered_friend is returned to you in that `ordered_friend`'s username. But having obtained an `ordered_friend`, you then do `ordered_friend.friend` but this is not the column that you orderd by so it's not surprising that the items don't get printed in alphabetical order. You porbably meant to do

```
print ordered_friend.user.first_name, ordered_friend.user.last_name
```

or did you perhaps intend to sort by friend in the first place?

```
Friendships.objects.filter(user__id=1).order_by('friend__first_name')
```

Comment: +e4c5 - Thank you, you're completely right that I mistakingly ordered by the *wrong column value* in my ord statement...I meant `.order_by('friend_first_name')` so that I could sort by friend. You have no idea what a huge help this was, thank you so greatly for your full response, including your conjecture in the end (you hit it spot on)! // edit: I was struggling to make sure that my double underscore `.order_by('<foreign_key>__<column_value>')` was taking, but I failed to see that I was looking into the wrong column :)

Comment: Glad to have been of help